# создаю ветку bugfix от главной ветки main

Tags: git, github, git-branch

объясните, пожалуйста, следующую вещь. Допустим, у меня есть ветка rl-1,  по этой ветке внесли комментарии и мне нужно создать  еще одну ветку bugfix/rl-1 и я ее должен создать из main. Но  изменения которые были в ветке rl-1  я не мерджил в main и не должен этого делать.  Новая ветка bugfix/rl-1 у меня не содержит  изменения из ветки rl-1 , она выглядит так же как и main, потому что эту ветку я создал из main. Какой командой мне подтянуть в ветку  bugfix/rl-1 всё то что есть в rl-1 ?

Comment: ну, например, merge.

Comment: имеется ввиду перейти в ветку bugfix/rl-1 и сделать команду git merge rl-1 ?

Comment: ну, например, да.

Comment: почему-то мне казалось,  что merge применителен только для main, а его  можно и по веткам  использовать. Спасибо!

Comment: main точно такая же ветка как и любая другая. Вернее, любая другая ветка точно такая да, как и main.

Comment: Стоит переспросить у того кто ставил задание. Зачем ветку bugfix/rl-1 создавать от main, а не от rl-1 ?